# Java core. Непонятно поведение программы

Tags: java, core

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При прохождении курса Java fundamentals внутри intelij idea.
Таска:

> A programmer of a smart room system is asked to turn on the fan whenever the temperature goes over 24 and the dehumidifier whenever the humidity rises beyond 0.7 (70%).
> However, if the smartMode option is turned on (true), only the fan may be activated.
> In which of these situations the code does not work as intended?

Варианты ответа:

```
Select one or more options from the list:

When smart mode is on, humidity is 40% and temperature is 20.

When smart mode is off, humidity is 80% and temperature is 24.

When smart mode is off, humidity is 70% and temperature is 30.

When smart mode is on, humidity is 90% and temperature is 27.
```

Код:

```
public class SmartRoom
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double temperature; //in Celsius degrees
      double humidity; //as a percentage
      boolean smartMode;

      /*
      The previous variables have been assigned hidden values here.
      */

      if (smartMode) //if smartMode is true, then...
      {
         if (humidity > 0.7) //if humidity is greater than 0.7 then...
            System.out.println("Dehumidifier activated.");
         else //else, if the humidity is lower, then...
            System.out.println("Smart save mode on. Only fan activated.");
      }
      else //else, if smartMode is false, then...
      {
         if (humidity > 0.7) //if humidity is greater than 0.7 then...
            System.out.println("Dehumidifier activated.");
         else if (temperature > 24) //else, if the humidity is lower, then...
            System.out.println("Fan activated.");
      }
   }
}
```

Считаю, что правильный ответ этот:

```
When smart mode is on, humidity is 90% and temperature is 27.
```

Если я не прав, опишите пожалуйста, почему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего два варианта в ответе, первый тоже неправильный т.к. включится вентилятор в ветке else, но температура 20<24 и он включаться не должен при этом значении.

Comment: Да, похоже варианты 1 и 4 неправильные.

Comment: Да, но все равно считает, что ответ некорректен

Comment: Судя по [комментариям к плагину](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18905-java-for-beginners/reviews#review=68319), они уже несколько месяцев пытаются исправить эту задачу и каждый раз ошибка в ней всплывает заново, требуя выбрать еще третий вариант: `"When smart mode is off, humidity is 70% and temperature is 30." answer to be checked to evaluate the solution as correct, meanwhile in this third scenario the smart room should function as intended.`

Comment: @AlexKrass Тот случай, когда на граничных условиях погорели не отвечающие, а сами авторы задачи )

Comment: и то верно)
спасибо!)